# Xamarin Forms: Image Captured from Xamarin forms is not getting displayed in Android Device

Tags: image, xamarin.forms

I am developing an xamarin forms application. I am able to click the image from camera, but the clicked image is not getting displayed in device. But the image picked from gallery is getting displayed in Device.

I am using the below code to capture the image:

```
//code to click pic
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
{
 await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
 return;
}
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
 SaveToAlbum = true,
 Directory = "DiscussionForum",
 Name = "test.jpg"
});
if (file == null)
return;
//await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");
filePath = file.Path;
fileStream = file.GetStream();
btn_profile_pic.Source = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
 var stream = file.GetStream();
 file.Dispose();
 return stream;
});
```

If I pick the captured image from gallery, I am able to display the image. Please let me know what change do I need to make. I am using Media Plugin library.

Comment: Try setting your image in the main thread with Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread ();

Comment: Look closely in your debug output, it will probably have message which state that your image is too big. There are some options in the plugin to get a smaller version of the image.